# Creating a h5py file data.hy and each data point contains multi-dimensional file

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I'm following this repository (https://github.com/gitlimlab/SSGAN-Tensorflow) and trying to use my own dataset. As mention there

> Store your data as an h5py file datasets/YOUR_DATASET/data.hy and each
> data point contains
>
> 'image': has shape [h, w, c], where c is the
> number of channels (grayscale images: 1, color images: 3)
>
> 'label':
> represented as an one-hot vector

I could not find something that helps in creating a file with same extension `data.hy`  but I tried to follow the main tutorial on h5py:

```
import h5py 
f = h5py.File("dataset.hy", "w")
dataset = f.create_dataset("default", shape=(3,10)) #I have ten classes
```

but to check that the initialization is correct I printed `datatset[0]` which gave the following output

```
In [7]: dataset.shape
Out[7]: (3, 10)
In [8]: dataset[0]
Out[8]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

This obviously means that I did not shape the dataset correctly but I don't know how to fix it. *I know that the h5py follows the same was as numpy shaping but not sure how to fix it in here.*

EDIT:
What I want to do is to fix the shape of the dataset so each point has two columns, each has a 1-d vector with a different number of elements e.g.

`[[h,w,c],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]`

Comment: You created a 3x10 array.  You printed the first row.   It has 10 elements.  What is wrong?

Comment: I want to create an array with two columns; the first one is 3-d vector and the second one is a 10-d vector.

Comment: That's not how `shape` works.  An array with shape `(3,10)` is a 3 x 10 array (30 elements) not a `(3,)` array and a `(10,)` array (13 elements)

Comment: When you say "a 10-d vector" do you mean ten numbers, or a TEN DIMENSIONAL vector, e.g. 4x3x9x2x5x9x3x3x4x2 = 699840 numbers?

Comment: @JohnZwinck ten numbers like this [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: That's a 1-d vector.

Comment: @JohnZwinck My bad, I'll fix it above, thanks

Comment: It's still not clear what output you want, though.

Comment: @DanielF I've just updated the thread, what I want to fix the shape so each data point has the following shape: `[[h,w,c],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]`

Comment: That's not what your docstring is asking for though.  It's asking for a `(h,w,c)` shaped array and a `(n,)` shaped one-hot vector (where you have n=10).  That isn't a numpy array, that's a dictionary, most likely

Comment: @DanielF but how is that different than what I descriped?

Comment: What you described isn't even a `numpy` array, it's "ragged" (i.e. not rectangular), and therefore will throw errors in nearly every function that takes `ndarray` as input.

Comment: That doc description is a little vague, confusing `dataset` and `data point`.  I'd like to see an example or the code that loads such a file.